# How to re-build URL to make sure parameter sent

Tags: php

I'm making a function that can perform queries to `maps.googleapis.com`. I use the library `GuzzleHttp` assistance.

The problem I faced is when I create a function and try to access the functionality by adding parameters in URL. Looks like this function doesn't known parameters (unallocated) consequently the function that I made did not work properly.

**My Controller**

```
public function actionGetalldata() {
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=alskdsbeKASDJldkd&types=geocode&language=id&input=paci";

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $res = $client->request('GET', $url);

    $data = $res->getBody();

    $array = json_decode($data, true);

    foreach ($array['predictions'] as $key) {
        $detail = $this->getLatLong($key['place_id']);
    }
}
```

You see... When I try to loop my whole data, I call `getLatLong` function but always **fail** because the function can not accept the parameters that I provide.

Below is the function

```
function getLatLong($placeid) {

    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=".$placeid."&key=alskdsbeKASDJldkd";

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $res = $client->request('GET', $url);

    $data = $res->getBody();

    $array = json_decode($data, true);

    $resultx = $array['result'];

    $id       = $resultx['id'];
    $placeid  = $resultx['place_id'];
    $alamat   = $resultx['adr_address'];
    $lat      = $resultx['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $long     = $resultx['geometry']['location']['lng'];

    $allData = [
        'id' => $id,
        'place_id' => $placeid,
        'address' => $alamat,
        'lat' => $lat,
        'long' => $long
    ];

    return $allData;
}
```

It looks like the `$placeid` variable is the cause.

If I directly place a static `placeid` value, this function working.

How can I fix it? Please help

Thank you

Comment: Is the 1st api call returning any results?

Comment: @Steve Yes. The result like :

ChIJI1Q3EFHxaS4RF7luqS5LmD8 

(I show one of the few)

This is `Place ID`